# How to get files and filenames persisted in k8s volume that come from SFTP server?

Tags: python, kubernetes, sftp

I have deployed an SFTP server in a pod where data is persisted in a persistent volume.

These files are sql dump files.

I would like to do the following in Kubernetes :

1. Set up a Kafka producer and consumer in Python
2. Write a Python script to monitor the persistent volume for new dump files
3. Connect the Python script with the Kafka producer to send messages when a new file is detected
4. Set up a Kafka consumer to listen for these messages and trigger the impdp process

I am stuck in point 2. "Write a Python script to monitor the persistent volume for new dump files"

I tried the following wit K8S API for Python:

```
from kubernetes import client, config 

# Load Kubernetes configuration
config.load_kube_config()

# Create Kubernetes API client 
api_client = client.CoreV1Api()
 
# Retrieve data from persistent volume claim 
data = api_client.read_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim(name='01-claim1', namespace='dev-01')
```

But it doesn't list files that are in SFTP or in persistent volume.

What is the best way to know when a new file from SFTP arrive in persistent volume, get this file in another pod that will execute sql command to import dump in database ?

Maybe there is another way than using Python script (I think I cannot directly access the files in a Persistent Volume (PV) using the Kubernetes API, because the Kubernetes API is not designed for reading or writing files), or maybe it is not possible and I have to find something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the directory on the kubelet, and connect to it directly, not just list the PVC. Then, you need possibly be using `paramiko` or other SFTP specific python library. The k8s client doesn't give you direct file access to any unmounted PVC, I believe.

Alternatively, Kafka Connect has an SFTP Connector. Or there's Apache Nifi, among other tools that can work with both SFTP and Kafka.

Otherwise, run some fswatch script on the SFTP server itself, and bypass k8s resources completely.